# Skyrim HearthFire

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

When I load up Skyrim on my Xbox 360, it pops up with select storage device I select the one with my save and DLC. Moments later it pops on the text onto the screen 'Loading Add-ons' this Is where the problem starts I tried using toothpaste on the disc I checked all solutions non worked right now am looking on my screen and it says the same 'loading Add-ons' this has been on for 2 hours. anybody with solutions? Thanks (However I don't think/know if it is the dlc itself doing the glitch) this has been going on for 2 weeks :/

Comment: First off, back up your save :P  Can you try deleting the DLC in the storage menu and then try loading the game again?  If that works, try re-downloading the DLC.

Comment: Okay I am now downloading the dlc back on. And it worked thanks bro.

Comment: No problem!  I made an answer, if you click the green check mark it will mark this question as solved, in case someone else has a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments, I suggested deleting and re-downloading the DLC.  This seems to have worked!